# contact since localhost to db hostinger

Tags: codeigniter, localhost, database-connection, remote-access

For work at the moment i need access from localhost of my computer (with Codeigniter) to DB into a server hostinger.

How can make it? How can change the configuration of phpmyadmin? I only want connect with my codeigniter to a remote DB.

I also accept a good server that permise me allow remote connection.

Comment: first you should figure out if external connections are even allowed on the server where the database is hosted

Comment: hostinger already said me that the c-panel that they offer can't action this. because i'm asking it. i know that all the servers can change the configuration, but i don't know how do it.

Comment: so are you using a vps or a host from them? if you have a vps you can easely in phpmyadmin set up a user account that has access from `%` aka all machines instead of just local, if not then you cant do anything.

Comment: i'm using a host from them

Comment: then you cant do much, you have to atleast get a vps or the host company have to set up an sql account which has external access